# How to specify different colors with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(size=4)
```

Suppose you have the above `scatterplot`. How can you specify that the points that are `>= 25` mpg will be plotted `red`, the one `between 20 and 25` `green` and the `0-20` `blue`?

Can this be done with `ggplot` specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this in two steps:

First, you define the groups that should have different colours; either by adding another column to the data frame or inside `aes`. I’ll use `aes` here:

```
aes(wt, mpg, color = cut(mpg, breaks = c(0, 20, 25, Inf)))
```

Secondly, by specifying a manual colour or fill scale:

```
scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'green', 'red'),
                   limits = c('(0,20]', '(20,25]', '(25,Inf]'))
```

This specifies which colours to use (`values`) and which labels to assign them to (`limits`); these are the names of the grouping generated by `cut`.

Taken together:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes(wt, mpg, color = cut(mpg, breaks = c(0, 20, 25, Inf))) +
    geom_point(size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'green', 'red'),
                       limits = c('(0,20]', '(20,25]', '(25,Inf]'))
```

You can improve the legend title by adding the grouping as a separate column to your data, or by providing a `guides` function call:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(title = 'mpg range'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure it can, although this type of work if probably best suited to working with your data frame before `ggplot()`. You could use `ifelse()` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(size = 4, 
               aes(color = ifelse(mpg > 25, "> 25", 
                                  ifelse(mpg > 20, "20-25", "< 20")))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("> 25" = "red", "< 20" = "blue", "20-25" = "green"),
                     name = "MPG"  )
```

[image]

You don't need to call `guides()` to create a title you can pass it to the `name = ..` argument in `scale_color_manual()`

Comment: Careful: the colour names in the code don’t correspond to the colours in the plot. It’s pure coincidence that they more or less match (well in fact they don’t, they are mismatched).

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red" = "red","blue" = "blue","green" = "green"))` to avoid the problem @KonradRudolph mentioned. Also, try to create the `color` variable as a dataset column in order to have a better legend/title.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys, I used part of you suggestions/critics to update