# Color specific points in plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m struggling with ggplot2. Actually I want to color some specific points in my scatter plot.

Let me explain my problem with the "mtcars" data.
I have plotted "mpg" against "wt".

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```

After this I want to highlight all cars with hp of 180 (blue) and 110(red), the rest should stay black.

If I use

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg,col=factor(hp))) + geom_point()
```

Then every different hp is colored.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/42114180/786542

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    horse_power = case_when(
      hp == 180 ~ "180 hp",
      hp == 110 ~ "110 hp",
      T ~ "else"
    )
  )

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = horse_power)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual("Horse power", values = c("red", "blue", "green")) +
  labs(
    x = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
    y = "Miles/(US) gallon"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ozan147! But how can also decide, which colors the specific points should have?

Comment: @Trigger; I updated my answer accordingly to include manual colors.

Comment: Thanks, does it also work with factors. I used the mtcars just as an example for my problem. The Points which I want to highlight are "factors" and not numeric. @Ozan147

Comment: @Trigger; it would work if you correctly adjust the cases inside `case_when` so that you are checking for correct types, characters instead of integers for example.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks! But I couldn´t figured it out! Because this post was labeled as a duplicate, I opened a new one with my real data frame and problem. The title is "Highlight several specific points using ggplot 2", maybe you can help me there! @Ozan147